# MYSQL - syntax error, unexpected '@', expecting $end

Tags: mysql, sql, full-text-search

I'm trying to write a **full-text search** with the following SQL syntax:

```
SELECT   u.usuario AS `id`,
         Concat('(', u.usuario, ') ', u.nombre) AS `text`
FROM     usuarios AS u
WHERE    u.cuenta_id = 10
AND      MATCH (u.terminos) against ('jacuna@sgc.gov.co' IN boolean mode)
ORDER BY u.usuario ASC
LIMIT    50
```

- **u.usuario** stores userID's string value
- **u.nombre** stores user's full name
- **u.terminos** stores some concatenated values to be used with AGAINST

Example:

if a user has the id *'123456'* and full name *'john doe'*, the MySQL column 'terminos' will contain *id + full name* which means '123456 john doe'

**Note** Sometimes user id can be an email, for that reason, it would have '@' character. When **AGAINST** value contains '@' I'm getting this error:

> Syntax error, unexpected '@', expecting $end

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put the phrase in double-quotes inside the single-quoted string.

I tested this on MySQL 5.6:

```
mysql> SELECT u.usuario, terminos
  FROM usuarios AS u
  WHERE u.cuenta_id = 10 AND
       MATCH (u.terminos) AGAINST ('"jacuna@sgc.gov.co"' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
+---------+------------------------+
| usuario | terminos               |
+---------+------------------------+
|       1 | call jacuna@sgc.gov.co |
+---------+------------------------+
```

Read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-boolean.html:

> A phrase that is enclosed within double quote (") characters matches only rows that contain the phrase literally, as it was typed. The full-text engine splits the phrase into words and performs a search in the FULLTEXT index for the words. Nonword characters need not be matched exactly: Phrase searching requires only that matches contain exactly the same words as the phrase and in the same order. For example, "test phrase" matches "test, phrase".

Comment: it doesn't work when using `('+"jacuna@sgc.gov.co"*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)`