# MySQL function generates pseudo-random syntax error

Tags: mysql

I have the following MySQL query implemented in PHP. I use statements to prevent SQL-injection.
The query scans a database of articles and search for the word $derired_word. If the word is contained in the article's title it is weighted 1000, in the summary 100 and if is contained in the text only 10. Two JOINs retrieve additional infos (I have here simplified the actual query).
I have a FULLTEXT index for all the parameters in the MATCH().

```
       $stmt = $conn->prepare(
        "SELECT a.articleTitle, a.articleSummary, a.articleText, a.articleText2, a.date, b.tags, b.icon, c.user

        MATCH (a.articleTitle) AGAINST ((?) IN BOOLEAN MODE) * 1000 AS rel1,
        MATCH (a.articleSummary) AGAINST ((?) IN BOOLEAN MODE) * 100 AS rel2,
        MATCH (a.articleText, a.articleText2) AGAINST ((?) IN BOOLEAN MODE) * 10 AS rel3

        FROM table_a a
        INNER JOIN table_b b ON (a.id = b.id)
        INNER JOIN table_c c ON a.id = c.id
        
        WHERE MATCH (articleTitle, articleSummary, articleText, articleText2) 
        
        AGAINST ((?) IN BOOLEAN MODE)
        
        ORDER BY (rel1)+(rel2)+(rel3) DESC
                            
        LIMIT 10");
    
        $stmt->bind_param("ssss", $derired_word, $derired_word, $derired_word, $derired_word);
```

The query produces the following error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: syntax error, unexpected '+' in /var/www/html/a.php:7371
> Stack trace:
> #0 /var/www/html/a.php(7371): mysqli_stmt->execute()
> #1 /var/www/html/a.php(9234): call()
> #2 /var/www/html/call2.php(428): call3()
> #3 {main}
> thrown in /var/www/html/a.php on line 7371, referer: https://xxxxxx

what surprise me is that the unexpected character ('+' in this case) seems to be pseudo-random as every time the function is called I have a different one (@, ), -, $end). It is like the statement is not properly working and the query is interpreting the input data as code.

any idea?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include your source code as a working [mcve], which can be tested by others to provide an answer faster.

Comment: you have 5 bind parameters but only 4 `?` that I see?

Comment: no, i have 4 bin parameters

Comment: What is the value of `$desired_word` when this happens?

Comment: It sounds like your code running in production is using variable interpolation instead of bound parameters. Are you sure you have deployed your recent code change?

Comment: what means variable interpolation instead of bound parameters?

Comment: it is a normal LAMP stack with default settings. all other queries are running fine

Comment: Variable interpolation is old-style PHP where variables are evaluated within the SQL string: `"SELECT ... WHERE MATCH ... AGAINST ('$derired_word' IN BOOLEAN MODE)"` This is what we try to avoid by using query parameters, because the risk is that the variable introduces SQL syntax errors. I'm suggesting that the code running in your production is using the old-style, even though the code you show above uses query parameters.

Comment: @Barman, from the apache's log i cannot tell you the value of $desired_word, but seems to be a problem of the MATCH(). I also have sometimes "unexpected '@', expecting $end" like here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57381338/mysql-syntax-error-unexpected-expecting-end

Comment: thanks @Bill for the explanation the code running on the server is exactly the one I have provided here (with statements). I have found another question here on SO with the same error. (see message above). It seems to be related to MATCH but on thet question there are not many answers

Comment: according to https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-boolean.html

 - InnoDB full-text search does not support the use of a leading plus sign with wildcard ('+*'), a plus and minus sign combination ('+-'), or leading a plus and minus sign combination ('+-apple'). These invalid queries return a syntax error.
   
 - InnoDB full-text search does not support the use of the @ symbol in
   boolean full-text searches. The @ symbol is reserved for use by the
   @distance pro....

Could be that I receive the error if the text contains one of the symbols @, +, ... ???
how can be fixed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is what you're passing to `against`. [Boolean full text search has a specific syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-boolean.html), and you're passing it things with syntax errors. The error depends on the values you pass in, so it seems "random". MySQL is not being helpful with its no-context error message.

```
select match (field) against(('123+') in boolean mode) from test;

syntax error, unexpected $end
```

[Demonstration](https://dbfiddle.uk/f1QGKgIo).

You have to properly escape the value in `$derired_word` or use a different fulltext search mode.

Comment: thank you! this is exactly the problem. Is there a standard way to sanitize $derired_word (that is provided by the user and on which I have no control)?

Comment: @carla Boolean search does not appear to provide an escape character. You can strip the special characters from your words. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26507087/escape-string-for-use-in-mysql-fulltext-search#26537463